Proof a curve is a geodesic on a sphere S
Here's my problem on the textbook:
Prove that the curve $c(t) = (6\cos t, 6\sin t, 0) $ is a geodesic on the sphere $S$: $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 36$
The definition of a geodesic in my text book is:
"A geodesic is a curve $c(t)$ of a regular surface $S$ if: $c''(t) \perp T_{c(t)}S, \,\forall t \in I$".
$T_{c(t)}S$ is the tangent space of $S$ at $c(t)$.
How could I deal with this problem using the definition ?

Try to think how to "define" the tangent plane. Given the equation for a sphere as an implicit function $F$, you can find it's gradient, which is normal to the surface of the sphere, i. e., it's perpendicular to the $T_pS , , \forall p$. If you are able to show that $\nabla F$ is collinear to $c''(t)$, then you're done.

I've tried  this way, but the problem is: the parametric equation of the sphere is X(u, v), but the parametric equation of the curve is c(t), they have different variable, then i don't know what to do next :((

Since $c'' = a c$, its evident that its orthogonal to $\mathit S^2$ in $\mathbb R^3$, by its definition. In other words, any curve with acceleration in $\mathbb R^3$ not parallel to itself is not a greatest circle. Parametrization is irrelevant.

omg, thank you so much <3 , i've complicated it :(

The definition is wrong unless one assumes $c(t)$ is a constant-speed curve!

no it's not, $c(t)$ is a constant-speed curve is the corollary from the definition

I'll still post a solution because it could be handy in terms of the surfaces more complicated than a sphere.
The basic idea was to somehow define the tangent plane, or, rather, separate it from the other planes as the given point on $c(t)$. To do that, let's rewrite the equation of the sphere as an implicit function:
$$
F(x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 36
$$
and try and find its gradient, which is known to be orthogonal to the level sets.
Easily found,
$$
\nabla F = 
\left[ 
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} , 
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}, 
\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}
\right]
=\left[ 2x , 2y, 2z\right]
$$
Since we know the parametrisation of the curve, we can find the family of gradient vectors along that curve, substituting:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
x &=& 6\cos{t} \\
y &=& 6\sin{t} \\
z &=& 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Hence, at any point $t$ along the given curve, the gradient is:
$$
\nabla F(t) = 12 \left[ \cos{t} , \sin{t}, 0\right]
$$
The second derivative of the $c(t)$ is instantly calculated:
$$
c''(t) = -6 \left[ \cos{t} , \sin{t}, 0\right]
$$
Since the gradient and the second derivative are collinear as every $t$, it means that $c''(t)$ is perpendicular to the tangent plane, as is the gradient, hence, it's a geodesic curve by definition.
